# Finding the expectation value of a wave function in parts

Tags: probability, expectation

I'm given a wave function (pg. 13 Griffith's 2nd  ed, #1.7)

$\Psi(x,0) = Ax/a \qquad if \qquad 0\le x \le a  $

$\Psi(x,0) = A(b-x)/(b-a) \quad if \quad a\le x \le b  $

$\Psi(x,0) = 0 \quad if \quad b\lt x  $

Now, I've normalized $ \Psi $ and can find the probability of any given area, but I'm not sure how to approach finding $ \langle x \rangle $ when the function is given piecemeal like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would simply be
\begin{align}
\langle x\rangle &=\int_0^b dx\,x\vert\Psi(x,0)\vert^2\, ,\\
&=\int_0^a dx\, x\vert\Psi(x,0)\vert^2 + \int_a^b dx\, x\vert\Psi(x,0)\vert^2
\end{align}
with the appropriate piece of $\Psi(x,0)$ on the appropriate interval.
The fact that it's piecewise isn't an issue.